# Correct Place to put .p12 File in a Java Web Application?

Tags: java, web-applications

I am trying to access a .p12 in my java web application. Where is the correct place to put the file and what line of code do I need to access the file as an InputStream. I am using the line below, but the class is not finding the file.

I currently have the file in WEB-INF/classes/theFile and am using:

InputStream inputStream =    this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("nameOfTheFile.p12");

to access the file

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer works for any file, not just ".p12" files.

Put a "/" in front of the name of your file (so, "/nameOfTheFile.p12" in your case) to specify an absolute path that will be resolved by using the classpath (which includes the WEB-INF/classes directory).

When you use a path without a leading "/", it is a relative path (vs. absolute path), specifically relative to the working directory of Tomcat or whatever container you are using. Even if you can find your resource using a relative path, you should not; doing so will end up hard coding deployment/packaging details within your application.